# Laravel groudby use day()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my sql is

```
select * from patient group by day(created_at) order by created_at"
```

but my use laravel ,i think use Model

```
Patient_Model::groupBy("DAY(created_at)")
        ->orderBy("created_at","desc")
        ->get();
```

this is error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DAY(created_at)' in 'group statement' (SQL: select * from `patients` group by `DAY(created_at)` order by `created_at` desc)
```

How uese day() in laravel5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use it with `DB::raw()` like so :

```
Patient_Model::
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'))
    ->orderBy("created_at","desc")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
 groupBy(\DB::raw("DAY(created_at)"))
```

Comment: yes , i try too ,success ,thank you ,but not use \ ,also success